# How to reverse a Reed - Solomon algorithm?

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, barcode

I have a Reedsolomon encoding algorithm,if i passes 3 values as parameters to that algorithm, then it returns error code words as output.Now i want to reverse of it,means if i passes error code words as input,then i want to get 3 values as output.How can i do it?

Comment: Your title is to general, how about asking for Reedsolomon decoding, if that's what you need?

Comment: First of all, please select only one language, the solution in C# will most likely be very different from the one in C++. Secondly, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: After 2 mins of searching http://www.eccpage.com/